# Prevent app from crashing without giving info when dll is missing

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, assembly-resolution

If some dll required by my VB.NET program is missing, when I run it, it crashes with the typical Windows error message, and does not provide any information about the error.

So, I thought of validating that all dependencies are satisfied before doing anything. But this is not trivial because I have unmanaged and runtime dependencies. So, before delving into that, is there some CLR setting, or some easier solution for this issue?

Comment: If you have no clue what runtime dependencies you have then you can always find out from SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  You'll see your program searching for the DLLs.

Comment: Yes. But I also have C++/CLI assemblies built with the /clr switch which reference unmanaged C++ assemblies. Not sure what to do with those. I mean, I know which assembly references which, the thing is validating their existence in a generic way, without hardcoding the whole dependency tree.

Comment: Right, that's what ProcMon will show you.  Doing this in less than 2 minutes isn't possible, you actually have to try it.  Nobody can guess what you'll see.  If you want better advice then ask for help from the owners of the DLLs you use.  They invariably have deployment instructions available.

Comment: Even if I know which dlls my program needs, it will still crash without giving info when one is missing. That looks nasty. I want to show a message box saying "XXX.dll missing. Reinstalling the app might fix the problem". I have seen many programs do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really easy (avoiding Windows' boilerplate message, that is). You just have to make your application handle the [UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.unhandledexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) event.

For a VB.NET app windows forms like mine, that meant going to the project properties, `Application` tab and clicking the `View Application events` button.

That opened the (hidden by default) ApplicationEvents.vb file. I added some code:

```
Namespace My

    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' 
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                                     ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs _
                                                     ) Handles Me.UnhandledException
            MessageBox.Show("Application crashed due to the following unhandled exception. " + e.Exception.ToString())
        End Sub

    End Class    

End Namespace
```

Now, if I'm missing some dll, I get its name, if it's managed or mixed, in the exception message. If the missing dll is unmanaged, I get just the name of the mixed assembly which needs it. But that's ok with me; throwing the mixed assembly on Depends.exe quickly reveals the offending unmanaged assembly.